# When doing mapping with slam_toolbox, can we move robot with goal setting?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

During ROS1, we can have gmapping and move_base node to do slam. While mapping, we can move robot around by setting goal in rviz window.

However, I am not sure how to do this in ROS2 with [slam_toolbox](https://github.com/SteveMacenski/slam_toolbox). According to [nav 2 tutorial](https://navigation.ros.org/tutorials/docs/navigation2_with_slam.html#working-with-slam), this is possible. Unfortunately, my robot was not moving at all after receiving the goal_pose.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/411451/when-doing-mapping-with-slam_toolbox,-can-we-move-robot-with-goal-setting?/) by [Cullen SUN](https://answers.ros.org/users/113591/cullen-sun/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2023-01-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

it is exactly the same for ROS 2 - I do it all the time while developing :-)

Did you follow the tutorial?

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2023-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cullen SUN](https://answers.ros.org/users/113591/cullen-sun/) on 2023-01-20**:
Thank you Steve for your reply. It turned out that i missed this step
`ros2 launch nav2_bringup navigation_launch.py`

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2023-01-20**:
That's a pretty important step :-)